# In ws-security under UsernameToken, is <sp:NoPassword/> not a valid assertion?

Tags: apache-axis, ws-security, rampart, usernametoken

We are implementing the web services using Apache Axis2 and integrating with WS-Security (using Apache Rampart module) too.

We are trying to define the Ws-Security policy that does  **NOT force the consumer to send the password** in Usernametoken because we verify only the user name against the database - The actual authentication is performed through key exchange ( asymmetric binding) mechanism.

When we tried with the below assertion, Axis2 simply ignored *NoPassword*.

```
<sp:SupportingTokens>
    <wsp:Policy>
      <sp:UsernameToken>
        <wsp:Policy>
          <sp:NoPassword/>
        </wsp:Policy>
      </sp:UsernameToken>
    </wsp:Policy>
</sp:SupportingTokens>
```

In *Ws-Security*, **is *NoPassword* not a valid assertion ?**

Framework:

Apache Axis2 v1.6.2

Apache Rampart v1.6.2

Answer (score 0):

It is a valid policy assertion in WS-Security Policy 1.2, but it is not defined for the policy language 1.1. Write your policy in 1.2, then Apache Rampart would do the job for you. Please look at this JIRA[1] for more info.

[1] - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/RAMPART-385

Comment: Thanks for spending time to look into the question.Now when I try to implement with WS Security Policy 1.2 having AsymmetricBinding 
and UsernameToken (SupportingTokens) assertions, I see a few issues - Please see the details at the [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18990151/in-apache-axis2-rampart-while-generating-wsdl-and-validating-policy-is-ws-secu) asked to that effect.