# In Apache Axis2/Rampart, while generating wsdl and validating policy, is Ws-security Policy 1.2 assertion <sp:NoPassword/> not handled completely?

Tags: apache, apache-axis, ws-security, rampart

We are implementing WS-Security Policy on our web services with the following framework/module/specification.

Apache Axis2 1.6.2
 Apache Rampart 1.6.2
 WS-Security Policy 1.2(namespace:http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702)

We are facing the following issues while creating/consuming the service.

1. Axis2 wsdl generation logic ignores `<sp:NoPassword/>` assertion. After debugging,I realized that it is because of the logic in org.apache.ws.secpolicy.model.UsernameToken (rampart-policy-1.6.2.jar) that expects 
   `<sp:WssUsernameToken11 />` ( or  `<sp:WssUsernameToken10 />`) to be specified - again when I specify that, the `<sp:NoPassword/>` is created as child element of `<sp:WssUsernameToken11 />` which was causing `<sp:NoPassword/>` to get ignored on the client (consumer) side.
2. In the implementation of `org.apache.rampart.PolicyBasedResultsValidator/handleSupportingTokens` method - NoPassword scenario is not considerd ; hence it always fails saying "org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: UsernameToken missing in request".
3. On the consumer side, for WS Security policy 1.2 to work, we had to remove rahas-1.6.2.mar from client side rampart repository;there is a JIRA ticket too -  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/RAMPART-371

Please suggest if I missed something here.